# What are the configuration are required for basic authentication to run automation code for Microsoft Edge 44 version?

Tags: automation, windows-10, microsoft-edge, basic-authentication, katalon-studio

need to run my automation script on edge browser(version 44) but I don't know how to handle basic authentication in Edge.

Is there any specific configuration for Edge?

My OS: Windows 10.

I am using Katalon Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this article](https://github.com/katalon-studio/docs/blob/master/pages/katalon-studio/docs/authorization-basic.md):

*You pass in your username and password to authenticate the request. It will be encoded to 'Authorization' request's headers as you can see below.*
[image]

About using Katalon studio with Microsoft edge web driver, first, please Install WebDriver for Microsoft Edge version 18 and newer:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Then refer to the following code and link to do the web automated testing (need to change the ChromeDriver to EdgeDriver):

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
String baseUrl = "https://www.katalon.com/";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://katalon-demo-cura.herokuapp.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("btn-make-appointment")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("txt-username")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("txt-username")).sendKeys("John Doe");
driver.findElement(By.id("txt-password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("txt-password")).sendKeys("ThisIsNotAPassword");
driver.findElement(By.id("btn-login")).click();
driver.quit();
```

[Introduction to Web Testing](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/introduction-to-web-testing.html#before-you-begin)

[Troubleshooting web automated testing](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/troubleshooting-web-automated-testing.html#timed-out-waiting-for-driver-server-to-start)